# I have git repo with one branch: master. How do I rename the branch locally and on the remote repo?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I have a git repo with a single branch: the master branch. Instead, I'd like for the master branch to be called "somethingelse", that way later I can add more branches with other names. I don't want to have a branch called "master".

How do I do it?

Comment: Why don't you want a `master` branch, I don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps should work, assuming that the name of your remote is `origin`:

```
# Rename local master to somethingelse
git branch -m master somethingelse

# Delete the remote named origin's master
git push origin :master

# Checkout local somethingelse
git checkout somethingelse

# Push the branch somethingelse to remote
git push origin somethingelse

# Update the remote tracking branch for somethingelse
# otherwise the next pull/push might fail
git branch -u origin/somethingelse somethingelse
```

These steps have lot of problems:

- No existing checkouts will know about the branch rename
- The next `git pull` will give you an error when no branch named `master` exists on the remote. The reason being the default branch is non-existent on the remote server. To update the default branch on the remote server, using the `git symbolic-ref` command I've mentioned at the end.
- In newer git versions, to delete the branch on the remote, you need to configure `receive.denyDeleteCurrent` to either `warn` or `ignore`, otherwise it won't let you perform the deletion. If you're unable to change the configuration on the remote, you won't be able to delete the branch on the remote. Although you could reset the branch master to somewhere else in the tree and do a `push -f`.

**Changing the default branch on the remote server:**

You need to have access to the remote server to configure the default branch that would be checked out on a fresh clone:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/somethingelse
```

Comment: Thanks tuxdude. What I did: your first step (renaming), then delete the remote repo, then create a new bare repo, then your third and fourth steps. Now, if I try cloning the remote repo in a new location, it says "`warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.`. But then I go into the cloned repo, and do `git checkout somethingelse` and everything seems to be fine. Will I always get that warning message when i have no "master" branch?

Comment: Note, I'm the only one accessing the repos, so no problem with checkouts by other people. It's just my private local and remote repos. EDIT: and I have root access on local and the remote.

Comment: @trusktr - I've updated the answer with that information. Yes you need to always have some default branch configured on the remote, otherwise you would get that warning on every `clone`.

Comment: How do I make "somethingelse" the default branch?

Comment: When I try that, it says `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. The remote is a bare repo. Can I push the setting?

Comment: @trusktr - You need to run `symbolic-ref` directly on the remote server, you cannot push that change.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! I forgot that my git is aliased to "git add .; git" so it spits that message, but it worked.

Comment: So when I clone, it works fine... One last issue, so in the original repo that I pushed to remote from, if I do git pull it says `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.`. How do we fix that? I guess I could delete the repo and clone from the new remote, but I'd prefer not to because it's the original repo where everything came from.

Comment: You need to update the remote tracking branch in your local repo. `git branch -u origin/somethingelse somethingelse` should do the trick.

Comment: Cool, and that outputs `Branch somethingelse set up to track remote branch somethingelse from origin.`. Thanks for the help!